# Using Jython From Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, python, jython

I am having a tough time getting jython to work properly when run from an Eclipse plugin.  I have a simple object factory that loads a python module conforming to a Java Interface.  All of this works fine in standalone mode.  However, when I package this as an eclipse plugin, I get a different error based on a few variables:

Given that my java package is com.foo.

1)  If I run without modifying any paths, I get: "No module named foo"

2)  If I then add my java jars to the sys.path using:

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
PySystemState sys = Py.getSystemState();
sys.path.append(new PyString("myjar..."));
```

I get:

a) My python module's constructor gets called (print in the constr shows up)
b) I get a PySingleton returned from the call to **tojava**.  The name field is "Error".

3)  At this point, I try to make the classpath exactly the same in Eclipse as Standalone, so I add my jars to the classpath at runtime just before the python interpreter is called.

I get my favorite error message: SystemError: Automatic proxy initialization should only occur on proxy classes

This one is driving me crazy.  I was impressed with how fast I got this going in standalone mode.  Should running under Eclipse be that much different?  I believe it should only be a matter of the classpath, but so far, that doesn't seem to be it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figure this one out.  Here is what I had to do:

1)  I used the JSR223 ScriptEngine instead of PythonInterpreter:

`engine.get(module_name); //gets the class object of the module
getConstructors[0].newInstance(null) on the class to get an object

//cast it to your interface!`

2) Make sure your Eclipse plugin isn't packaged as a jar (in 3.5 set Eclipse-BundleShape: dir)
3) Add jython.jar and any paths where you want to locate modules to your Runtime Classpath in the Manifest.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your question was unrelated to my problem but 3) Add jython.jar and any paths where you want to locate modules to your Runtime Classpath in the Manifest. that comment helped me out so much using python modules in eclipse.